# how to design a table like what is in microsoft word in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to design a table in android like what we design in microsoft word
how can i do that.
i can not change the size of tables in android manually.i will appreciate if some body help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a library for that :

https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders